# Is there a standalone visual editor for WPF XAML files?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

**Is there a stand-alone visual (WYSIWYG) editor for WPF xaml files like the Visual Studio 2010 designer?**

The VS2010 one crashes all the time and is very slow (there are lots of threads on XAML slowness in VS, but all the recommendations seem to point to editing the XML files with a text-based editor). I want a visual one as I'm very new to WPF and it would help me a lot.

Currently I have set gVim to open up .xaml files, **but editing the raw XML file is not easy if you don't know all the possible options / elements / properties / attributes you have available**.

I used to use Qt, and the Qt Designer application also edited XML files that specified how the UI is laid-out. It was a stand-alone application, and you never had to actually edit the XML content with a text-editor unless there was a bad problem.

Is there a WPF equivalent?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look at [Kaxaml](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/kaxaml) and see if it's what you need.

Comment: +1 for Kaxaml. It is handy. Also, check out XAMLPad http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742398%28VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Just had a go using Kaxaml and it feels fast and great. Autocomplete of xaml attributes and tags is working nicely.

Comment: This link looks really dodgy now.

Comment: link updated - now points to the Kaxaml project on gitHub

Comment: Would you please give your comment on using [XAML Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/xaml-studio/)? Although it is designed to function as a UWP interactive XAML Designer, Is it possible to use it for WPF projects? I'm planning to bypass Visual Studio and use some designer with VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

Try XAMLPad which is in the Windows SDK from Microsoft. KaXAML has not been updated in quite some time from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik allows you to edit text in xaml as you want:
http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#RichTextBox/TelerikEditor